# API Call not working on TypeScript if only one object is returned

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I've got a task where I need to return 10 Chuck Norris jokes from an API. This part I got right but the second part (Get a random joke every 5 seconds) is breaking me a bit.

```
// Get jokes by amount
getJokes(amount) {
const jokeArray = [];
const randomJokeArray = [];
if(amount > 1){
  this.http.get(http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/' + amount).subscribe(data => {
    // Test to see if call was successful
    if(data["type"] === 'success'){
        for(var i = 0; i <= data["value"].length; i++){
          jokeArray.push(data["value"][i]);
        }
    } else {
      console.warn("API Call 'getJokes' was unsuccessful");
    }
  });
} else {
  this.http.get('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/' + amount).subscribe(data => {
    // Test to see if call was successful
    if(data["type"] === 'success'){
      randomJokeArray = data["value"][0];
      console.log(randomJokeArray);
    } else {
      console.warn("API Call 'getJokes' was unsuccessful");
    }
  });
}

    if(amount > 1){
      // Return the jokeArray
      return of (jokeArray);
    } else {
      return of (randomJokeArray);
    }

}
```

`randomJokeArray` always comes back as undefined.

This function is inside of a service and me being fairly new to TypeScript and Angular. I'm pretty sure I'm using it wrong. Can anyone please show me how I can return only one joke from the API?

If I duplicate the API call of 10 that works I get the following returned when only calling for 1.

From the main file

```
this.configService.getJokes(1).subscribe(j => this.randomJokeArray = j);
```

From the service file

```
for(var i = 0; i <= data["value"].length; i++){
    randomJokeArray.push(data["value"][i]);
}

return of (randomJokeArray);
```

[image: Returned Array]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you. I'm fresh with TypeScript and to be honest, I don't know if this is in fact a duplicate. I'm not using jQuery so can't test with ajax.

Comment: `randomJoke` or `randomJokeArray`? i don't see `randomJokeArray` and `randomJoke` will always be undefined because you have'nt set any values.

Comment: @Jai I messed up when I copied the code over. I've edited the question. It's only `randomJokeArray`

Comment: Ajax is a browser technology that jQuery has an implementation of. Angular also implements it via `this.http`. The point is that it is asynchronous, so you can't return the value you're retrieving until you've retrieved it. Right now, you're trying to eat your pizza before it's been delivered :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three issues in your code

1. Your component is subscribing to a `Subscription` not an `Observable`. So you should `map` on the response returned by `http` instead of subscribing, because you wish to return Observable to your component.

   ```
   this.http.get('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/' + amount).pipe(map(data => {
      // Test to see if call was successful
                .........................................
   }));
   ```
2. Main issue : You are not waiting for the asynchronous execution to be completed.

   Move your `if(amount > 1){...}` code inside `http.get.map()`

   ```
   return this.http.get('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/' + amount).pipe(map(data => {
       // Test to see if call was successful
       if(data["type"] === 'success'){
         randomJokeArray = data["value"][0];
         console.log(randomJokeArray);
       } else {
         console.warn("API Call 'getJokes' was unsuccessful");
       }

       if(amount > 1){
           // Return the jokeArray
           return of (jokeArray);
       } else {
           return of (randomJokeArray);
       }
   }));
   ```
3. add return statement before `http.get.map()`

   ```
   return this.http.get('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/' + amount).pipe(map(data => {
          // Test to see if call was successful
          .........................................
   }));
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You made effort to explain stuff but I'm afraid with my experience and implementation I still couldn't get it right. Even though your answer might be right. I feel that I shouldn't mark it as the answer as it might not help others...what do I do :|

Comment: What issue are you still facing? Did you make the above changes?

Comment: I still got undefined values returned but I'm sure it's not your code that is breaking it. I can mark yours as correct and close the issue. I'm carrying on learning and have my second interview today so holding thumbs that I was able to do enough with the other tasks. Thank you!

Comment: If you have time, you can reproduce your issue on stackblitz. Anyways happy learning and all the best for your career :)

Comment: Thank you sir. Any language starts off as hieroglyphs and then the day after it's english. :).

Comment: I hope, I atleast deserve an upvote to my answer. You can mark it later once your issue is solved or add your own answer for it.